# Compile a jruby on rails application to a jar?

Tags: jar, jruby, executable-jar, jrubyonrails

Is there a quick way to pack a jruby on rails application into a jar?

Is there an [ec2 on rails](http://ec2onrails.rubyforge.org/) like virtual appliance for jruby on rails apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Warbler 1.2.1](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) you can create an "executable" war file.

```
    gem install warbler
    warble executable war
    java -jar myrailsapp.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a JAR is just a zip file, you might be able to just zip it. The following article describes a successul process of making a jar from a rails app: http://matthewkwilliams.com/index.php/2010/03/02/rails-jruby-in-a-jar/